# Nintendo Switch and Power Bank

Tags: power

it's just one week until the nintendo switch is in stores and as I plan to play a lot I would like to know if I can connect it to my power bank? I have this doubt because my power bank just have an 1A and 2.1A port and as you can see in the image attached it says 2.6A. Thank you for your help. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your power bank is likely 5V or maybe 12V. The device in question needs 15V. Your power banks likely can't source (15V * 2.6A =) 31 Watts of output (more like 38 Watts when you take regulator efficiency into account).

So no.